# How to Flip Div's in Randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the application where All divs are Flip Vertically on hover. I wanted to make it random without hover. How should I do that?

```css
.vertical.flip-container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.vertical .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.vertical.flip-container .flipper {
  transform-origin: 100% 50px;
}

.vertical.flip-container:hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
}


/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front" style="background: red">
      Rushikesh
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="background:green">
      Jogle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front" style="background: red">
      Rushikesh
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="background:green">
      Jogle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front" style="background: red">
      Rushikesh
    </div>
    <div class="back" style="background:green">
      Jogle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be thankful.

Comment: Do you wan't to randomly flip them all or just some random number of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I simplified your markup and CSS quite a bit. Also gave it a more 3D look.
You can use setInterval to flip them hover:

**http://jsfiddle.net/7x75466y/5/**

```
var $flippers = $(".flip-container"),
    qtFlippers = $flippers.length;

setInterval(function () {
    $flippers.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*qtFlippers)).toggleClass('hover');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @Rushikeshjogle I updated the jsFiddle link with a new version that  supports horizontal flip (see first block).

Comment: @Rushikeshjogle That link only works for webkit browsers. For IE9 you should add the `-ms-` prefix to all CSS transformations. For mozilla `-moz-`. See http://caniuse.com/#search=transform. BTW do you really need that flipping in IE? http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Yes .. for Ie9 and above Or do you know any Jquery Library where i can make the Applicaton like this ?

Comment: You can see from the caniuse site, that IE9 does not support 3D transformations (only 2D with -ms- prefix). You can simply show the back div on hover, without animation. What's the big deal about having animation? Remember that content is still more important than presentation. IE9 users will miss that animation and will not even be aware of that. Go to http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/ for IE9 specific CSS. This way you leave animation available for real browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSfiddle that selects a random tile, and applies an action to it at every second (using setTimeout). You can perform whatever action you like on the tile. Using jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/7x75466y/2/

```
var containers = $(".flip-container")
setInterval(function() {
    var target = containers.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * containers.size()))
    target.fadeToggle() //DO WHAT YOU WANT TO THE TARGET
}, 1000)
```