# How to Flip Div's Randomly Back then Front Again

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, flip

**Reference:** [How to Flip Div's in Randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903974/how-to-flip-divs-in-randomly)  and The working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/7x75466y/5/

I have the above random image flipping script working on my site. Currently it flips a random image and lets it stay in that state, then moves on to another randome image and flips it and leaves it in that state, etc.

What I need it to "unflip" after each flip before moving on to the next random image.  Here is an example of how I want it to work: https://learnwithhomer.com/buzz/press/

Here is the jQuery in question:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $flippers = $(".flip-container"),
    qtFlippers = $flippers.length;

    setInterval(function () {
    $flippers.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*qtFlippers)).toggleClass('hover'); }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Not being snarky, but it really sounds like you're cutting and pasting, and don't actually know javascript. This site is for folks who are learning to program and need help along the way. If you need professional assistance for a product, you'll want to hire someone for that. Now, if I've got you all wrong, great! But you'll need to provide details on what you've tried, and what specific aspect of this problem has you stumped.

Comment: Thank you Shawn for input.  I am a novice at javascript.  I consider myself a "tweaker" not a coder.  I can usually figure out how to tweak it to get it to work, but I just don't know enough to get this one to work.  Now that I see the answer below I can see I was way out of my depths with this one because I was thinking the answer was going to be very different.  And this, unfortunately for me, is how I learn.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $flippers = $(".flip-container"),
    qtFlippers = $flippers.length;
var isFlipped = false;
var randomItem = -1
setInterval(function () {
    
    if (isFlipped && randomItem !== -1) {
     $flippers.eq(Math.floor(randomItem)).toggleClass('hover');
     isFlipped = false;
      randomItem = -1;
      return;
    }
    
    if (!isFlipped) {
      randomItem = Math.random()*qtFlippers;
     $flippers.eq(Math.floor(randomItem)).toggleClass('hover');
     isFlipped = true;
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
section {
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    perspective: 500px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.flip-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.flip-container > div > div {
    background: red;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.flip-container .flipper {
    transform-origin: 50px 100%;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.vertical.flip-container .flipper {
    transform-origin: 100% 50px;
}

.flip-container > div > div + div {
    background: green;
    transform: rotateX(180deg) scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1);
}
.vertical.flip-container > div > div + div {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}


/* flip the pane when hovered 
.flip-container:hover .flipper,*/
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/*.vertical.flip-container:hover .flipper,*/
.vertical.flip-container.hover .flipper{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.flip-container > div > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
        
    <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
        
    <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="flip-container vertical" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
   <div>Rushikesh</div>
   <div>Prudvi</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Is it like this your looking?

Comment: This is perfect!  It works great.  And now I see how you wrote the js to get the effect and I can see why what I was trying was incorrect.  Thank you so much!

Comment: To work in Safari you need to add -webkit, and for IE9 you need -ms.  So perspective would be:

`    perspective: 500px;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    -ms-perspective: 500px;`